# 3d object wont update in for loop

Tags: opengl, 3d, glkit

I am trying to rotate a 3d object but it doesnt update when applying transforms in a for loop.

The object jumps to the last position.

How does one update a 3d object's position in a sequence of updates if it wont update in a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just calling glTranslate, glRotate or such won't change things on the screen. Why? Because OpenGL is a plain drawing API, not a scene graph. All it knows about are points, lines and triangles that draws to a pixel framebuffer. That's it. You want to change something on the screen, you must *redraw* it, i.e. clear the picture, and draw it again, with the changes.

BTW: You should not use a dedicated loop to implement animations (neither for, nor while, nor do while). Instead perform animation in the idle handler and issue a redraw event.

Comment: I am using the GLKit.I update parameters and a GLKQuaternion, I don't get any visible updates on screen even though the update delegate is being called. The updates occur in touchesMoved, when I use the same code and try to loop using the difference between previousTouch and lastTouch in touchesEnded, I do not see any rotation on the image, even though the logs show new positions and rotation values. Could the loop be blocking the update method? I would like to take the last rotation in touchesMoved and apply it to the touchesEnded method to make the object rotate after the user has panned.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you have a wrong understanding what OpenGL does for you. 
I'll try to outline:

```
- Send vertex data to the GPU (once) 
      (this does only specify the (standard) shape of the object)

- Create matrices to rotate, translate or transform the object (per update)
- Send the matrices to the shader (per update)
      (The shader then calculates the screen position using the original 
       vertex position and the transformation matrix)
- Tell OpenGL to draw the bound vertices (per update)
```

Imagine programming with OpenGL like being a web client - only specifying the request (changing the matrix and binding stuff) is not enough, you need to explicitly send the request (send the transformation data and tell OpenGL to draw) to receive the answer (having objects on the screen.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to draw an animation from a loop.

```
for ( ...) {
  edit_transformation();
  draw();
  glFlush();   // maybe glutSwapBuffers() if you use GLUT
  usleep(100); // not standard C, bad
}
```

You draw, you flush/swap to make sure that what you just drew is sent to the screen, and you sleep.

However, it is **not recommended** to do this in an interactive application. The main reason is that while you are in this loop, nothing else can run. Your application will be unresponsive.

That's why window systems are event-based. Every few miliseconds, the window system pings your app so you can update your state, for example do animation. This is the *idle function*. When the state of your program changed, you tell the window system that you would like to draw again. It is then up the the window system to call your *display function*. You do your OpenGL calls when the system tells you to.

If you use GLUT for communicating with the window system, this looks like the code below. Other libraries [like GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) have equivalent functions.

```c
int main() {
  ...                       // Create window, set everything up.
  glutIdleFunc(update);     // Register idle function
  glutDisplayFunc(display); // Register display function
  glutMainLoop();           // The window system is in charge from here on.
}

void update() {
  edit_transformation();    // Update your models
  glutPostRedisplay();      // Tell the window system that something changed.
}

void display() {
    draw();                 // Your OpenGL code here.
    glFlush();              // or glutSwapBuffers();
}
```